# Using InMemoryUserDetailsManager with hashed password

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, authentication, kotlin

I'm trying to use an already hashed password with the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` but it doesn't seem to work the way I thought it would. Specifying the `{bcrypt}` prefix has absolutely not effect here and the string is being treated as plaintext. I have debugged the encoder's code and it encrypts the hash and adds its own prefix.

Is it supposed to work like that? I mean does the `User` expect a plain text password from me? I guess I probably need to implement my own password-encoder that would use bcrypt only when it doesn't already find the `{bcrypt}` prefix, right? Is this how you would do this or do I overlook some detail?

I currently have the following code:

```
object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        runApplication<LinguistApplication>(*args) {
            setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
            addInitializers(beans {
                bean {
                    InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                            User
                                    .withUsername("me-test")
                                    .password("{bcrypt}\$2a\$10\$buiY/E5s3yOU8KsAOLIF2OFvA9StUcRsSFojNpKzUn6lFsgeEolCK")
                                    //.passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                                    .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                                    .roles("USER")
                                    .build()
                    )
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The password you set is encrypted again. So the password is actually `{bcrypt}\$2a\$10\$buiY/E5s3yOU8KsAOLIF2OFvA9StUcRsSFojNpKzUn6lFsgeEolCK`. So to answer your question, yes the plain password should be put in there.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok... well, then this is rubbish - so as I assumed, I'll need a custom pasword-encryptor to handle this case. I had hoped spring could do a better job.

Comment: @M.Deinum any idea why spring uses it in its documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) - see at the end of the page where the `password` field also contains the hash. I think this should work but some piece is missing.

Comment: Because you are setting the password encoder it is encoded again. You shouldn't be setting the encoder OR use a plain password with the encoder. See the [javadoc of `passwordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.UserBuilder.html#passwordEncoder-java.util.function.Function-). So basically you are trying to outsmart an already smart(er) framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, I tried this and the matcher says that the hashes don't match :\ I debugged through the source code and the prefix and hash are correctly extracted, then the password is hashed with the current hash `return equalsNoEarlyReturn(hashed, hashpw(plaintext, hashed))` then the byte comparison result is `127 == 0` which is natrually false. This is strange because 127 = DEL

Comment: Your password is wrong, it contains `\$` why? That should be just `$`. And as stated don't set the encoder (at least NOT on the `UserBuilder`! or provide the plain password.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is because Kotlin treats `$` as a prefix for variable names inside a string so I escaped them. Yes, I removed the encoder and it is now determined by the `{bcrypt}` prefix and correctly resolved.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use a plain password is because I'd like to push it to github and would rather avoid revealing it.

Comment: Then why push to github (use a private repository then). If the code is public there is also documentation which probably i ncludes the password anyway. Nonetheless if you provide the encoded password it should work (or the password you entered/validate with isn't the one you actually used for encoding).

Comment: @M.Deinum oh boy. Facepalm. I generated the hash with https://bcrypt-generator.com and somehow it generates different hashes each time. I tried it with https://passwordhashing.com/BCrypt instead and now it works ;-) Thank you for your time and for the clues! ;-]

Comment: Well the hash should be different each time as the salt is randomized. So one does a proper randomize the other one probably uses a static salt then (which is why you get a constant value). Nonetheless glad it worked out.